# Fitting log-linear data

Tags: fitting, data, nonlinear

I am using NonlinearModelFit to extract the gradient of what appears to be linear data in a logplot:

```
data = {{-0.010133333333333334`, 
    124.50000000000001`}, {-0.006933333333333333`, 
    610.`}, {-0.005600000000000001`, 
    75.58333333333333`}, {-0.004266666666666669`, 
    33.183673469387756`}, {-0.0029333333333333295`, 
    17.23926380368098`}, {-0.0015999999999999973`, 
    5.47681331747919`}, {-0.00026666666666666505`, 
    1.3872715510270095`}, {0.0010666666666666672`, 
    0.3445990722332671`}, {0.0023999999999999994`, 
    0.0713022981732469`}, {0.0037333333333333316`, 
    0.05300353356890459`}, {0.005066666666666671`, 
    0.021496815286624203`}, {0.006400000000000003`, 
    0.0028530670470756064`}, {0.008266666666666665`, 
    0.004938271604938271`}};

expmodel = 
  NonlinearModelFit[data, a*Exp[b*x], {a, b}, x, MaxIterations -> 200];

Show[{
  ListLogPlot[data],
  LogPlot[expmodel[x], {x, -0.01, 0.005}]}]
```

The function returned by NonlinearModelFit, however, does not match the data at all. I even tried to give realistic initial values to parameters `a` and `b`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Why not take a Log to Y-axis value and use LinearModelFit?

Comment: If this help, I can post a detailed answer :)

Comment: @Wjx That was a good idea :)

Comment: So I will write an answer as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually we'll tend to fit linear system, and in this situaiton, add `Log` to data's y-axis will help: `Log[a E^(b x)]=Log[a]+b x`

Truely, after this transformation, the points lay on a line~ great for fitting!

[image: orig]

It seems that this method could really do the work, so naturally, here comes the following code for fitting using normal linear fitting method:

```
ldata = {#1, Log@#2} & @@@ data;
ListPlot@ldata
f[x_] = E^Normal@LinearModelFit[ldata, x, x]

Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Darker@Green, PlotLegends -> {"Data"}], 
Plot[f[x], {x, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, PlotLegends -> {"Fit"}]]
Show[ListLogPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Darker@Green,PlotLegends -> {"Data"}], 
Plot[Log@f[x], {x, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, PlotLegends -> {"Fit"}]]
```

The resultant function is: `E^(-0.0888526 - 717.01 x)` and the fitting curve is shown below:

[image: fit]

The result seems to be a bit wierd in normal scale, but in Log scale, it's quite a good fit!

Will this help?

Answer (score 1):

`FindFit` seems to work

```
f[a_, b_, x_] = a*Exp[b*x];
expmodel[x_] = f[a, b, x] /. FindFit[data,f[a, b, x],{a, b},x]
```

> 50.3816 E^(-167.73 x)

I will compare it with

```
f1[x_]=E^(-0.08885264746563443` - 717.0097150284254` x)
```

which can be found from Wjx's method.

```
Show[{ListPlot[data, PlotRange->All], Plot[{expmodel[x],f1[x]}, {x, -0.01, 0.01}]}]
Show[{ListLogPlot[data], LogPlot[{expmodel[x], f1[x]}, {x, -0.01, 0.01}]}]
```

[image]

Definitely `f1` appears much closer to data. Now if you calculate the RMS deviation

```
RootMeanSquare[(#[[2]] - expmodel[#[[1]]]) &/@ data]
RootMeanSquare[(#[[2]] - f1[#[[1]]]) &/@ data]
```

> 137.858
>
> 354.308

`expmodel` turns out to be the winner.

All these mess is due to your second data point. If you start from third data point Wjx's method will come pretty close to `FindFit`.

Comment: "`FindFit` seems to work" ???  With all of the data points very much below the fitted curve?

Comment: check my modified answer. It will clear your doubt.

Comment: But `f1` is simply the same structure as `expmodel`:  f1 == Exp[Log[a] + b*x] and should end up with the same fit.  So that's why I wonder about "FindFit" working.

Comment: @JimBaldwin, the fitting algorithm is different in two cases.

Comment: Sorry.  I see now.  `f1` is the antilog of the fit by @Wjx rather than a fit of `f1` directly.